# How to invoke a getter method by its name?

Tags: java, methods, getter

I have the following bean class:

```
public class A{
        private String field;

        public String getField() {
            return field;
        }

        private String setField(String field) {
            this.field = field;
        }

    }
```

And the following class:

```
    public class B{

         public static void main(String[] args){
             A a = new A();
             //do stuff
             String f = //get a's field value
         }
    }
```

How can I get the value returned by the getter of a particular object of `class A`? Of course, I can invoke method with `Method.invoke(Object obj, Object... args)` but I wouldn't like to write `"get"` prefix manually. Is it possible to avoid that?

Comment: You might want to look at `java.beans.Introspector`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Looks like what I'm looking for. Would you mind providing a complete answer?

Comment: @user3663882  [Check this tutorial](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=java.beans.BeanInfo)

Answer (score 58):

How about using [`java.beans.PropertyDescriptor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/beans/PropertyDescriptor.html) (assuming your property has correct *setter* and *getter* - so in your case you need to correct your `private String setField(String field)` setter since (a) its return type should be `void` not `String`, (b) it should be `public` not `private`).

```
Object f = new PropertyDescriptor("field", A.class).getReadMethod().invoke(a);
```

or little longer version (which does exactly same as previous one)

```
PropertyDescriptor pd = new PropertyDescriptor("field", A.class);
Method getter = pd.getReadMethod();
Object f = getter.invoke(a);
```

`PropertyDescriptor` allows us to do many things, for instance its [`getReadMethod()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyDescriptor.html#getReadMethod--)

> Gets the method that should be used to read the property value.

So we can get instance of `java.reflect.Method` representing getter for `field`. All we need to do now is simply invoke it on bean from which we want to get result.

Comment: Great, thank you. Couldn't you amplify your answer with some normative refernces.

Comment: Read the PropertyDescriptor documentation : `PropertyDescriptor(String propertyName, Class<?> beanClass)` 
*Constructs a PropertyDescriptor for a property that follows the standard Java convention by having getFoo and setFoo accessor methods*.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Will the getter be invoked if we don't have a corresponding filed and setter, just `getField()`?

Comment: Yes. You can have readonly, writeonly, readwrite properties. Only methods are necessary, you may not have an associated field.

Comment: Superb example. I was wandering everywhere to find the most simplistic solution. This helped me at last.

Comment: Very simple, succinct and complete. Thank you.

Comment: This is a good solution but as @user3663882 suspected, the constructor throws an IntrospectionException if any of the getter/setter is absent. A better solution is to use `Introspector.getBeanInfo(...).getPropertyDescriptors()` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2638662) - it works fine even when only either is present.

Answer (score 8):

Another easy way is to use the basic java reflection.

```
Method fieldGetter = A.getClass().getMethod("getField");
String f = fieldGetter.invoke(A).toString();
```

As simple as that.
Cheers !!