# Realm java, how to access RealmObject property by string (reflection)

Tags: java, reflection, realm

I wanted to access the property of model by string via reflection like

```
Object o = ...; // The object you want to inspect
Class<?> c = o.getClass();

Field f = c.getField("myColor");
f.setAccessible(true);

String valueOfMyColor = (String) f.get(o);
```

But i was still getting error that the property doesn't exist. Then i found that RealmModel objects are wrapped with RealmProxy class so that could be the reason.

So question is, how to access RealmModel properties by string? Via reflection or another way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to either call `realmGet$fieldName()` method, or your getters like `getFieldName()` method

For example, I did this

```
public static String getFieldThroughGetterAsStringTransform(Object target, String property) {
    try {
        Method method = target.getClass().getMethod("get" + StringUtils.capitalize(property));
        Object getResult = method.invoke(target);
        return getResult != null ? getResult.toString() : null;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to map property [" + property + "] on object [" + target + "]");
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

And

```
String fieldValue = FieldTransformer.getFieldThroughGetterAsStringTransform(managedObject, fieldName);
```

But you can look at [other ways of calling getter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2638662/2413303), like Apache Commons BeanUtils:

```
Object value = PropertyUtils.getProperty(person, "name");
```

Comment: bit messy but thx, btw you know how is it possible that in code works the access on original RealmObject properties but via reflection not? if it works in code it must works also via reflection?

Comment: Because the field is null, the getters call a native method of the proxy that reads from the Realm directly

Answer (score 2):

i prefer to `copyFromRealm` this object and reflect it as regular object